# Identify pivot table slicers that belong to a particular worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, slicers

I've an Excel workbook with 20+ tabs.
 Each tab has one pivot table and can have 20+ slicers. 
Worksheet "Origin" has the slicer set up that can be shared (with minor modifications) with all the other worksheets 
I've already developed code that will copy all slicers and attach them to the relevant pivottable on the other sheets. Unique slicer names are created during this process.
I now want to extend this so that I can use any sheet with a copied set of slicers as an "Origin". 
Here's where I run into problems as my renaming of the slicers currently loops through all the slicercache. Is there a means to identify the worksheet that a slicer belongs to?
 Below is part of my code where I obtain slicer information. It's a little messy as this is work in progress!
 Note: SlicerArray is a Type array.
The line with "****" is causing me problems if I start my process at any other sheet than the "Origin". (The initial items in the Slicercache belong to the Origin sheet so these shapes are not found when processing the cache from an alternate worksheet). I could get round this if I can identify the slicers belonging to that particular worksheet.

```
Dim slCaches As SlicerCaches
Dim slCache As SlicerCache
Dim SlicerInfo(100, 6)
Dim sh As Shape
Dim IntIndex As Integer
Dim SlicerArray(100) As SlicerRecord
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim jSlicers As Slicers
Dim kSlicer As Slicer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh_name As String


For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
   For Each slCache In slCaches
      For Each kSlicer In slCache.Slicers
         If kSlicer.Shape.TopLeftCell.Worksheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then
            Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(slCache.SourceName)'*****
             With SlicerArray(IntIndex)
                .PivotTable = pt.Name
                .Name = slCache.Name
                .SourceName = slCache.SourceName
                .Top = sh.Top
                .Left = sh.Left
                .Width = sh.Width
                .Height = sh.Height
                .Caption = kSlicer.Caption
                 With slCache.Slicers(slCache.SourceName)
                      SlicerArray(IntIndex).Columns = .NumberOfColumns
                 End With
                IntIndex = IntIndex + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next kSlicer
  Next slCache
Next pt
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer eventually. Linking the worksheet and the slicer name can be done via the the Pivot table Parent.Name property. I use the code below to populate another type array with the relevant Slicer names and related worksheet.

```
IntIndex = 0
For Each slCache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    For Each PT In slCache.PivotTables
        PT.Parent.Activate
        'Debug.Print Slcache.Name & "," & PT.Parent.Name
        With MySlicersSheetArray(IntIndex)
         .StrSlicerName = slCache.Name
         .StrSlicerSourceName = slCache.SourceName
         .strSheetName = PT.Parent.Name
        End With
    Next
    IntIndex = IntIndex + 1
Next
ws.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `kSlicer.name` instead of `slCache.SourceName`.  `kSlicer.name` is also the name of the object Shape.